# can i make this code shorter or better?

Tags: python

can i make this code shorter or better ?
because i feel the if line is not that great

```
import random as ra

out = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']


def match():
    p1, p2 = ra.choice(out), ra.choice(out)
    print('P1:', p1, 'x', 'P2:', p2)
    if p1 == p2:
        print('Draw', '\n')
    elif (p1 == 'rock' and p2 == 'scissor') or (p1 == 'paper' and p2 == 'rock') or (p1 == 'scissor' and p2 == 'paper'):
        print('P1 win', '\n')
    else:
        print('P2 win', '\n')


for i in range(10):
    match()
```

Comment: Try codereview.stackexchange.com for these kinds of questions.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Look at [codereview.se]

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 Please do not vote to close with a custom reason that "it belongs on Code Review". Nothing in the Stack Overflow rules justifies such a custom reason, and sloppy reasoning perpetuates inappropriate referrals. Not all questions about analyzing code are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and not all code review requests are on-topic on Code Review. Instead, vote to close as too broad or primarily opinion-based. See also [the guide to CR for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Ok, I'll take note of that

Answer (score 2):

Better? I don't know. Shorter? Yep. Not by much though.

```
import random as ra
gestures = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'] # order here is important
def match():
    p1, p2 = ra.randint(0, 2), ra.randint(0, 2)
    print(f"P1: {gestures[p1]} x P2: {gestures[p2]}")
    if p1 == p2:
        print("tie")
    else:
        print(f"p{(p1-p2)%3} won")

for i in range(10):
    match()
```

Can go even shorter

```
import random as ra
def rock_paper_scissors():
    gestures = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'] # order here is important
    p1, p2 = ra.randint(0, 2), ra.randint(0, 2)
    return "P1: {0}, x P2: {1}, Result: {2}".format(gestures[p1], gestures[p2], {0: 'tie', 1: 'p1', 2: 'p2'}[(p1-p2)%3])

for i in range(10):
    print(match())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll claim this is both *shorter* and *better*:

```
from random import choice

BEATEN_BY = {'rock': ['scissors'], 'paper': ['rock'], 'scissors': ['paper']}

def match(p1, p2):
    print('P1:', p1, 'x', 'P2:', p2)

    if p1 == p2:
        print('Draw\n')
    else:
        print('P1' if p2 in BEATEN_BY[p1] else 'P2', 'wins\n')

for _ in range(10):
    choices = list(BEATEN_BY)

    match(choice(choices), choice(choices))
```

Although it looks like I was wasteful making the values lists instead of strings, and used `in` instead of `==`, this is where *better* comes in again, as now we can simply do:

```
BEATEN_BY = {
    'rock': ['scissors', 'lizard'],
    'paper': ['rock', 'Spock'],
    'scissors': ['paper', 'lizard'],
    'lizard': ['paper', 'Spock'],
    'Spock': ['rock', 'scissors']
}
```